# Why can't you cast number into struct directly in C?

Tags: c, struct

I have struct defined as:

```
typedef struct cr3_page_entry
{
   uint64_t ignored     : 2;   // ignored
   uint64_t pwt         : 1;   // page-level write-through; indirectly determines the memory type used to access the PML4 table during linear-address translation (see Section 4.9.2)
   uint64_t pcd         : 1;   // page-level cache disable; indirectly determines the memory type used to access the PML4 table during linear-address translation (see Section 4.9.2)
   uint64_t ignored2    : 7;   // ignored
   uint64_t address     : 53;  // rest is address up to MAXPHYADDR, then zeros
} cr3_page_entry_t;
```

which is a uint64_t, if you look at it (64bit sized struct). Now, I have an assembler function that returns such a number from it

```
extern uint64_t get_active_page();
```

however, I can't directly cast to it:

```
cr3_page_entry_t entry = (cr3_page_entry_t) get_active_page();
```

because I get an error:

```
memory/paging.c:19:2: error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
  cr3_page_entry_t entry = (cr3_page_entry_t) get_active_page();
```

can this be done without making a another stack variable for some pointer casting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `union` with `uint64_t` and `cr3_page_entry_t` structure. Then assign to `uint64_t` member.

```
typedef union _cr3_u
{
   uint64_t i;
   cr3_page_entry_t str;
} cr3_u;

cr3_u my_data;

my_data.i = get_active_page();
```

Comment: for bonus points: `cr3_page_entry_t entry = (my_data.i = get_active_page(), my_data.str);`

Answer (score 3):

The most portable solution is to `memcpy()` between the struct instance and a `uint64_t` variable.  C99 and later (and many compilers older than that) allow type-punning through a union.  In both cases, the exact layout of the bits in your bitfield is unspecified, so you should check that it’s what you expect on your compiler.  A less-safe solution is `*(uint64_t*)(&struct_instance)`.  Be sure to confirm with `static_assert()` or `#ifdef` that `sizeof(struct cr3_page_entry) == sizeof(uint64_t)`.  You should also check that the alignment of your fields is what you expect, if you care about portability between compilers.

One reason you can’t do this is that the internal layout of bitfields isn’t specified.  The compiler does not have to pack them, or even align them at a valid address for a 64-bit integer.  For example, on Sparc 64, a `uint64_t` must be aligned on an 8-byte boundary, so if you write a bunch of small bitfields and the compiler aligns them as if they were `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` or `uint32_t`, trying to load the struct as a `uint64_t` will crash the program with a bus error.

Comment: The option with `&` is not usable in OP's code because the returned value is not an lvalue. An intermediate named variable would need to be used

Comment: In C type punning with `unions` is completely ok. This is what they were invented for.

Comment: @JensGustedt To be more precise, in C99 and later, type-punning is legal and won’t ever crash the program with a hardware trap. However, it still might not work if the compiler doesn’t pack the bits the way you expected: for example, the struct might have extra padding. Probably not a realistic concern in this case, since it depends on a particular CPU’s instruction anyway.

Comment: @Lorehead, yes, but that problem is not specific to `union`. Viewing through a different pointer type as you are proposing doesn't solve that problem.

Comment: @JensGustedt I said that was even less safe.  But, yes, the unspecified layout of the type would be equally a problem with `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you avoid the cast altogether by declaring:

```
extern uint64_t get_active_page();
```

as:

```
extern cr3_page_entry_t get_active_page();
```

instead?

Comment: As long as the `get_active_page` function definition is changed to match. Mismatching declaration and definition causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: yes this is what I used, because get_active_page is written in assembly anyways, so it returns int value and does not care about type

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't allow you to cast to a struct type. In 99% of cases this wouldn't make sense, your case is a rare exception.

I'd recommend the following:

```
static inline struct cr3_page_entry make_cr3_page_entry(uint64_t x)
{
    struct cr3_page_entry ret;
    assert( sizeof ret == sizeof x );
    memcpy( &ret, &x, sizeof x );
    return ret;
}
```

Note: using an aliasing cast instead would violate the strict aliasing rule.